# relation between Holder continuous and weakly differentiable for the coefficients of a pde

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading a book on pdes and the author gives the definition of the weak solution using the adjoint operator. For that expression to make sense, for the case of second order elliptic equation one has to have the coefficient to have second, first weak derivative, depending which partial derivative they come with. Later, he states the existence result and requires the coefficients to be $\alpha$ Holder continuous. Thus, I am confused, is the space of Holder continuous functions inside of the space of the functions with weak derivatives? If I just require the coefficients to be Holder continuous does it imply they also have weak derivatives? From a related post in mathoverflow I found a counterexample and therefore not sure how to relate that to what I see in the pde book.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which book are you using? what is the precise result? 

For linear uniformly elliptic equations, existence results in a Sobolev space do not require Holder continuous coefficients, although certain regularity results do.

Comment: You might find your answers here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38751/a-h%C3%B6lder-continuous-function-which-does-not-belong-to-any-sobolev-space

Answer (score 1):

You can embed certain Sobolev spaces into Holder spaces. It of course depends upon the dimension of the domain, the number of derivatives, which $L^p$ space, etc..

See the [Sobolev embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality).